# How to answer admin password prompt in os in python

Tags: python, cmd, operating-system, runas

I've lately found a way to run any program as administrator in cmd in Windows 10:

```
runas /user:"John" "cmd /c regedit"
```

and I wanted to recreate this in python:

```
os.system('runas /user:"John" "cmd /c regedit"')
```

The problem is that I need to write down password and it seems that os skips that. How can I add password information to this code? Any other better alternatives of achieving same goal welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use something like pexpect instead of os.system
https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

```
process = pexpect.spawn('runas /user:"John" "cmd /c regedit"')
process.expect("Password:") // or whatever else you are prompted with
process.sendline("*******") // your password
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Python gives me error: AttributeError: module 'pexpect' has no attribute 'spawn'